# iPhone Photo Album Animation

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, photos

Is it possible to have Photo Album kind of animation in our own application? I want to group a set of views together to simulate the feeling of stacked pages, then spread the same using two fingers. Is it possible?

Is there a simple example I can use?

Comment: Of course it's possible. The Photos app does it, no?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using CoreImage. Here is Mac sample using that do it in iPhone. All the best.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CITransitionSelectorSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009470

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using UIAnimation & Transformation

Comment: Upper sample app is not like the iPad phto app. Are there any sample code like iPad photo app?