# Opening Photo Album Animation

Tags: ios, animation

I just like to ask if anyone has tried creating the animation effect similar to opening an album in iOS Photo app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Guess you mean on the iPad Photo app, since on the iPhone it is simply a navigation controller and a table view.

Maybe more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6288992/1197572

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are right, it is the iPad Photo app.